# DataGrid is not bound to the ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a button in my view that execute this method in the ViewModel:

```
public void GetAudits(Guid? userId, DateTime? from, DateTime? to, string form)
        {
            StringBuilder sCondition = new StringBuilder("WHERE 0=0");

            if (userId != null && userId != Guid.Empty)
                sCondition.Append(string.Format(" AND UserId = '{0}' ", userId));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form))
                sCondition.Append(string.Format(" AND FormName = '{0}' ", form));


            string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Common.TbHistoryLog {0}", sCondition);
            Audits = new ObservableCollection<HistoryLog>(oContext.Database.SqlQuery<HistoryLog>(query).ToList());

        }
```

the `Audits` property:

```
 public ObservableCollection<HistoryLog> Audits
    {
        get
        {
            return audits;
        }
        set
        {
            audits = value;
        }
    }
    ObservableCollection<HistoryLog> audits;
```

and this is the handler for the button:

```
private void BtnSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var userId = ((TbUsers)cmbUsers.SelectedItem)?.UserId;
            var from = dtFromDate.Value;
            var to = dtToDate.Value;
            var form = ((BlCommon.TbObjects)cmbForms.SelectedItem)?.ObjectRealName;
            using (ClsUserTransactions oUserTrans = new ClsUserTransactions())
            {
                oUserTrans.GetAudits(userId, from, to, form);
            }
        }
```

but when I click the button, the dataGrid doesn't get updated with the Audits collection:

```
<DataGrid  Name="gvHistory" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9" Margin="2" Visibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding Audits}" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.RowSpan="2"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False"/>
```

When I debug, I notice that the getter block is not hit

Comment: implement INotifyPropertyChanged in ViewModel and raise PropertyChanged event  for "Audits" property in setter

Comment: Observable collection properties should be read only.  They provide change notification to the UI.  Add and remove elements from the collection, don't replace the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply clear and re-populate the same `ObservableCollection`?:

```
public void GetAudits(Guid? userId, DateTime? from, DateTime? to, string form)
{
    StringBuilder sCondition = new StringBuilder("WHERE 0=0");

    if (userId != null && userId != Guid.Empty)
        sCondition.Append(string.Format(" AND UserId = '{0}' ", userId));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form))
        sCondition.Append(string.Format(" AND FormName = '{0}' ", form));


    string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Common.TbHistoryLog {0}", sCondition);
    if (Audits != null)
    {
        Audits.Clear();
        var newItems = oContext.Database.SqlQuery<HistoryLog>(query).ToList();
        if (newItems != null)
            foreach (var newItem in newItems)
                Audits.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

Second, this creates a *new instance* of `ClsUserTransactions`:

```
ClsUserTransactions oUserTrans = new ClsUserTransactions())
```

You need to add items to the one that the `DataGrid` is bound to and you certainly shouldn't dispose the instance immediately after you have populated its Audits collection...:

```
private void BtnSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var userId = ((TbUsers)cmbUsers.SelectedItem)?.UserId;
    var from = dtFromDate.Value;
    var to = dtToDate.Value;
    var form = ((BlCommon.TbObjects)cmbForms.SelectedItem)?.ObjectRealName;
    ClsUserTransactions oUserTrans = gvHistory.DataContext as ClsUserTransactions;
    oUserTrans.GetAudits(userId, from, to, form);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your ViewModel should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, then notify the property change on the Audits setter:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
...
```

-

```
public ObservableCollection<HistoryLog> Audits
{
    get
    {
        return audits;
    }
    set
    {
        audits = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Audits");
    }
}
ObservableCollection<HistoryLog> audits;
```